# getelementsbytagname for xml response text not working

Tags: xml, vba, api, xml-documentation

I'm having trouble figuring out why my code isn't recognizing the tagname "HourlySchedule". When it gets to: `For Each HourlySchedule In Resp.getElementsByTagName("HourlySchedule")`, it will skip to the end instead of looping thru each tag. I've tried several different tag names and it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

My VBA code:

```
    Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim URL As String: URL = "webaddress here"
    Dim mfile As String
    mfile = "<?xml version=" & """" & "1.0" & """" & "?><Envelope xmlns=" & """" & "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" & """" & "><Header/><Body><QueryRequest xmlns=" & """" & "http://markets.midwestiso.org/dar/xml" & """" & "><QueryMarketResults day=" & """" & "2017-03-05" & """" & "><LocationName>Rug</LocationName></QueryMarketResults></QueryRequest></Body></Envelope>"

    Set Req = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    With Req
        .Open "POST", URL, False
        .SetClientCertificate "CURRENT_USER\MY\name"
        .SetRequestHeader "content-type", "text/xml"
        .Send (mfile)
        .WaitForResponse
    End With

    Dim Resp As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Resp.LoadXML Req.ResponseText

if Resp.loadxml (Req.ResponseText) then
   MsgBox "ok" else
   MsgBox "err"
end if

    Dim HourlySchedule As IXMLDOMNode
    For Each HourlySchedule In Resp.getElementsByTagName("HourlySchedule") ''this is where my problem is
    Debug.Print "test"
    Next HourlySchedule
    End Sub
```

Here is the xml i'm trying to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <QueryResponse xmlns="http://markets.midwestiso.org/dart/xml">
            <MarketResults day="2017-03-05">
                <Location name="OTP.RUGBY1_IBR">
                    <HourlySchedule hour="1">
                        <ClearedEnergy MW="-6" virtualMW="0" price="7" capped="false"/>
                        <ClearedReg MW="0" price="10.18" capped="false"/>
                        <ClearedSpin MW="0" price="1" capped="false"/>
                        <ClearedSupp MW="0" price="0.5" capped="false"/>
                        <ClearedRampCapabilityUp MW="0" price="0"/>
                        <ClearedRampCapabilityDown MW="0" price="0"/>
                    </HourlySchedule>
                    <HourlySchedule hour="2">
                        <ClearedEnergy MW="-2" virtualMW="0" price="5.3" capped="false"/>
                        <ClearedReg MW="0" price="8.06" capped="false"/>
                        <ClearedSpin MW="0" price="1" capped="false"/>
                        <ClearedSupp MW="0" price="0.5" capped="false"/>
                        <ClearedRampCapabilityUp MW="0" price="0"/>
                        <ClearedRampCapabilityDown MW="0" price="0"/>
                    </HourlySchedule>
                </Location>
            </MarketResults>
        </QueryResponse>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Comment: `myfile` is anything, but not XML. Please make a syntactically valid VB string or that contains syntactically valid XML - or put the XML file into a separate code block for reference.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that there is a parsing error and the response document is not really loaded. Check the [`parseError` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms756041(v=vs.85).aspx) (in fact you *always* should check for parsing errors after loading an XML document). In a more general context, instead of `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest`, I recommend using `MSXML2.XMLHTTP60` request object, as this will transparently do the XML parsing for you (just access its [`responseXml` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757066(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I'm somewhat new to parsing xml. Can you give an example of how I can make myfile syntactically valid VB string? Thank you.

Comment: There is no way your code looks like what you show in the upper box. It's not valid VB, you will get syntax errors. Show the code you are using, not something you just made up for the question. And there is no way the XML you send looks like this in real live because that is not syntactically valid, either. Show the XML you are using and not something you just made up for the question. Your question is about code that *works* but produces the wrong result. Why would you post code that does not work, then?

Comment: I have updated the mfile with the full code that I am using. However, I changed the name of the location for security reasons. Thanks again for taking a look.

Comment: I updated my vba code above to show how I checked that the xml loaded ok. I attempted using MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 instead of WinHttpRequest. However, when using .XMLHTTP60 it didn't allow for the .setclientcertificate to be used. Any further suggestions to help me understand why getElementsByTagName is not returning a value would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An often cited issue in parsing XML documents is an undeclared namespace prefix which your response contains twice at different node levels. Notice no colon separated name is included which is a perfectly valid XML:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

<QueryResponse xmlns="http://markets.midwestiso.org/dart/xml">
```

As a result, in VBA declare such namespaces by designating user-defined prefixes, here *doc* and *doc2* is used. Then, using `SelectNodes` method over `getElementsByTagName` since you will need to reference the second defined prefix as *HourlySchedule* is a child of *Query* node, you can then query to the needed element:

```vb
...
   Dim HourlySchedule As IXMLDOMNode    
   Dim XmlNamespaces As String

   ' SPACE SEPARATED STRING
   XmlNamespaces = "xmlns:doc='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'" _
                   & " xmlns:doc2='http://markets.midwestiso.org/dart/xml'"
   Resp.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", XmlNamespaces

   For Each HourlySchedule In Resp.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//doc2:HourlySchedule")
       Debug.Print "test"
   Next HourlySchedule

   Set Resp = Nothing 

End Sub
```

**Output** *(in Immediate Window)*

```
test
test
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much I never would have figured that out.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. Yes, for new XML users namespaces can be a very subtle overlook. Please accept solution (tick mark to side) to confirm resolution.