# getElementsByTagName and undeclared namespace

Tags: excel, xml, vba, soap, namespaces

I am working on a project to import request data to Excel using a SOAP call. I can return the XML no problem and it looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <RetrieveRequestsResponse xmlns="http://rapid2.library.colostate.edu/rapid5api/">
            <RetrieveRequestsResult>
                <IsSuccessful>true</IsSuccessful>
                <Transactions>
                    <Transaction>
                        <RapidRequestId>1111</RapidRequestId>
                        <XRefRequestId>[TN:11111]</XRefRequestId>
                        <StateType>Pending</StateType>
                        <RapidRequestType>Article</RapidRequestType>
                        <BorrowerRapidCode>###</BorrowerRapidCode>
                        <BorrowerCountryCode>AU</BorrowerCountryCode>
                    </Transaction>
                </Transactions>
            </RetrieveRequestsResult>
        </RetrieveRequestsResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

my problem occurs when I try to parse and display the XML in Excel.

Using [this excellent tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uo5TvtXuzJQ) I created the following code

```
Dim Resp As New DOMDocument60
Resp.LoadXML xmlhtp.responseText

Dim transaction As IXMLDOMNode
Dim XmlNamespaces As String
Dim i As Integer

  XmlNamespaces = "xmlns:doc2='http://rapid2.library.colostate.edu/rapid5api/'
Resp.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", XmlNamespaces

For Each transaction In Resp.getElementsByTagName("Transaction")
 Debug.Print "tesst"
    i = i + 1
    WS.Range("A2:A200").Cells(1, i).Value = transaction.SelectNodes("//doc2:RapidRequestId")(0).Text

 Next Transaction

End With
End Sub
```

however this returns 'nothing' for transaction in Locals and skips over the loop when I debug.

After further research [I came across this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44194763/getelementsbytagname-for-xml-response-text-not-working) that seems to address my issue of an undeclared namespace?

```
<RetrieveRequestsResponse xmlns="http://rapid2.library.colostate.edu/rapid5api/">
```

After somewhat aimlessly tweaking my code I ended up with;

```
Dim Resp As New DOMDocument60
Resp.LoadXML xmlhtp.responseText

Dim Transaction As IXMLDOMNode
Dim XmlNamespaces As String
Dim i As Integer

XmlNamespaces = "xmlns:doc2='http://rapid2.library.colostate.edu/rapid5api/'"
Resp.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", XmlNamespaces

 For Each transaction In Resp.getElementsByTagName("Transaction")
  Debug.Print "tesst"                                                                                                          
     i = i + 1
     WS.Range("A2:A200").Cells(1, i).Value =  Transaction.SelectNodes("//doc2:RapidRequestId")(0).Text
 Next Transaction

End With
End Sub
```

This now returns two rows of RequestIDs, however they are both the same. Ideally what I need to be able to do is display the data from all nodes in

```
<Transaction>
```

Many thanks

Sam

Comment: Are there multiple transactions in your actual XML?  You posted example only has one.

Comment: @TimWilliams Hi Tim, there is only ever one Transactions, however there could be multiple Transaction depending on the number of requests that have been made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Dim Resp As New DOMDocument60

Resp.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
Resp.LoadXML Range("C1").Value '<<< loading from worksheet for testing

Dim Transaction As IXMLDOMNode
Dim XmlNamespaces As String
Dim i As Integer

XmlNamespaces = "xmlns:doc2='http://rapid2.library.colostate.edu/rapid5api/'"
Resp.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", XmlNamespaces

 For Each Transaction In Resp.SelectNodes("//doc2:Transaction")
    Debug.Print "--------------"
    Debug.Print Transaction.SelectSingleNode("doc2:RapidRequestId").Text
    Debug.Print Transaction.SelectSingleNode("doc2:XRefRequestId").Text
 Next Transaction
```

Comment: This is working exactly as intended in the Immediate window and I am certain when I had it printing the correct values in Excel last Friday, however today when I tested, it prints the same requestID twice, rather then moving to the next value. How can I get this values displaying in Excel ideally in a new row for each ID?

Comment: That code works for me (with my invented multi-transaction XML sample). If it did work for you, but now it's not, I'm not able to guess what  changed between those two times.